# Detect 64bit or 32bit OS and install VC10 vcredist file with Inno Setup Installer

Tags: inno-setup, vcredist

I want to add vcredist_x64.exe and vcredist_x86.exe with my Inno Setup installer. How my installer will detect the OS whether it is 64bit or 32bit and it will install the file vcredist file as per OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

in the [Files] section add

```
Source: "vcredist_x86.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: IgnoreVersion replacesameversion; Check: "not IsWin64";
Source: "vcredist_x64.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: IgnoreVersion replacesameversion; Check:IsWin64;
```

and in your [Code] section do:

```
function Launch_VCRedist(svDir:String) : Boolean;
var
  svTargetApplication: String;
  svParameter: String;
  workingDir: String;
  showCmd: Integer;
  wait: TExecWait;
  resultCode: Integer;  
  VersionMS, VersionLS : Cardinal;  
  Major, Minor, Rev, Build: Cardinal;
  Version:String;
begin
  Result := True;

 //Optional: if you want to execute silently your redist.exe, add this. This is  for vc_redist version from 2005 to 2012
      GetVersionNumbers(svDir + '\vcredist_x86.exe', VersionMS, VersionLS); 
      Major := VersionMS shr 16; 
      case Major of
        11:        //2012
         begin
            svParameter := '/install /passive';
         end   
        10:        //2010
         begin
            svParameter := '/passive /showfinalerror';
         end   
        6:         //2005            
         begin
           svParameter := '/q';
         end    
        9:         //2008            
         begin
           svParameter := '/Q';
         end
      end;

  workingDir := '';
  showCmd := SW_SHOW;
  wait := ewWaitUntilTerminated;
  retVal := Exec(svDir + '\vcredist_x86.exe', svParameter, workingDir, showCmd, wait, resultCode)
  if retVal then
  begin
    //handle success if necessary; resultCode contains the exit code
  end
  else begin
    //handle failure if necessary; resultCode contains the error code
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

And in CurStepChanged procedure add:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
     case CurStep of
      ssPostInstall:
         b_ret := Launch_VCRedist(ExpandConstant('{tmp}'));
        if b_ret Then
        begin
        //Handle success if necessary
      end
      else begin
        //Handle failure if necessary
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  In which section I will place below code block (And in CurStepChanged procedure add:). Please reply.

Comment: @user3606222 Those functions can be placed everywhere in the [Code] section. 

If you already have a CurStepChanged function inside your code section, add the b_ret := Launch_VCRedist(ExpandConstant('{tmp}')); like the example

Comment: Is that a typo? `Check: Check:IsWin64;`